# How to add IO to my own monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I wrote my own monad which is the State monad with error handling:

```
newtype MyMonad a = MyMonad (State -> Either MyError (State, a))
```

I use it in an interpreter of a small language. Now I want to add some IO operations to my language (reading/writing), but I don't know how to enclose IO monad inside mine. I know I could combine ErrorT, StateT, IO and achieve this result but is there other way to do it without them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at how [StateT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#StateT) is implemented:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

To combine state with `IO` you just put `IO` in place of `m` and get the desired type: `s -> IO (a,s)`.

If you have errors too, this becomes something like `s -> IO (Either e (a, s))` or `s -> IO (Either e a, s)` depending on whether you want the failed computations to affect state.

Note that you can't make `s -> Either e (IO (a, s))` a monad <strike>without a time machine</strike>.

**Update**

It turns out you can't make it a monad even with time machine.

To show why it is impossible, let us simplify our monad by using `()` instead of `s` first: `data M e a = M { runM :: Either e (IO a) }`

Now, imagine the following program:

```
unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a
unsafePerformIO io = fromLeft $ runM $ do
  a <- M $ Right $ io
  M $ Left a
```

Obviously, this function is impossible and thus the monad instance for `M` is impossible too.

What time machine could give you is the ability to treat `IO` exactly like one treats `State`. However, I didn't realise that `Either e (s -> (a, s))` is not a monad.

Comment: Time machine? Can you provide some context? Is it some "pun intended" joke, or is it some advanced mathematical/programming science term?

Comment: No puns here, I am talking about a real time machine. Once you have it, you can implement this monad.

Comment: @Rotsor: care to explain *why* said time machine is required?

Comment: It turns out the time machine doesn't help.

Comment: Time machines never help.